# mouse & keyboard keep reinstalling & network keeps identifying on login

Tags: windows-7

PC = Windows 7 Pro 64-bit desktop.

For about the last 1-2 weeks, after I login, Mouse and Keyboard Centre spends about 5-10 seconds "downloading" then disappears from the screen.

At the same time, my network connection is "identifying". It does this every time I login now, even though it is the same network, and nothing has changed on the network.

It's like the PC has forgotten some of its settings, and needs to be auto-configured again each time.

In the event log > system, there is an event:

> Event 1060: \SystemRoot\SysWow64\Drivers\GEARAspiWDM.sys has been
>   blocked from loading due to incompatibility with this system. Please
>   contact your software vendor for a compatible version of the driver.

This file's properties show:

[image]

Also in event viewer > system is:

> Event 7006: The ScRegSetValueExW call failed for Start with the
>   following error:  Access is denied.

Is this a process that tries to write to the registry, and fails due to access problems?

If I expand the event in XML format, I see:

[image]

If I search the registry for "9C38ED61-D565-4728-AEEE-C80952F0ECDE", I see:

[image]

Troubleshooting tips welcome.

Comment: The latest GEAR drivers, including the GEAR 64-bit drivers, are available [here](http://www.gearsoftware.com/support/drivers.php)

Comment: See [DRIVERS: Windows - Updating, removing, 64 bit versions, etc](http://www.gearsoftware.com/wiki/index.php?title=DRIVERS:_Windows_-_Updating%2C_removing%2C_64_bit_versions%2C_etc)

Comment: @DavidPostill: do you think the GEAR PC/DVD driver relates to the Microsoft Mouse & Keyboard Center downloading every boot?

Comment: There is clearly a problem with your gear driver failing to load correctly. I don't know what the side effects of this are.

Comment: OK. I've updated the driver as suggested, and the other symptoms remain @DavidPostill.

Comment: Maybe you should do a [repair install of windows](https://www.winhelp.us/non-destructive-reinstall-of-windows-7.html)?